# Service variable not updating in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a NavbarCtrl that is outside of ng-view. I have a login controller that talks to a service to get a user logged in. Once the user is logged in, I want the Navbar to update with the user's email address. However for the life of me, I can't seem to get the Navbar scope to update with the data that is loaded in to my "Auth" service once the user is logged in.

This is my main index.html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">Brim</a>

                <div class="pull-right"  ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
                    <div ng-click="refresh()">hello</div>
                    {{ user.email }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container" ng-view>
```

And my service:

```
.factory('Auth', function($resource) {
    var authenticated = false;
    var user = {};
    return {
        isAuthenticated: function () {
            return authenticated;
        },
        getUser: function() {
            return user;
        },
        login: function(loginUser, callback) {
            user =  {email:'email@email.com'}
            authenticated = true;
            callback(true);
            //actual code for logging in taken out for brevity
        }
    }
})
```

And my Login and Navbar controllers:

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $location, Auth) {

$scope.login = function() {
    Auth.login($scope.user, function(success) {
        if(success) $location.path('/dashboard');
        //console.log(Auth.getUser())
    });
}

}

function NavbarCtrl($scope, Auth)  {

//thought this should work
$scope.user = Auth.getUser();

//experimenting unsuccessfully with $watch
$scope.$watch(Auth.isAuthenticated(),function () {
    $scope.user = Auth.getUser()
})

//clicking on a refresh button is the only way I can get this to work
$scope.refresh = function() {
    $scope.user = Auth.getUser()
}
}
```

From my research I would have thought that $scope.user = Auth.getUser(); would work, but it's not and I'm at a complete loss as to how how I can get my Navbar updated when a user is logged in. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A little off-topic but wouldn't you also lose track of the authenticated user on refresh? Did you eventually expand this to utilize session storage?

Comment: Yes, I've been experimenting with session storage to keep track of the authenticated user. I've come across https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Update**: well, you learn something new every day... just remove the `()` to watch the results of a function:

```
$scope.$watch(Auth.isAuthenticated, function() { ... });
```

<kbd>[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/wzECr/2/)</kbd>

In this fiddle, notice how 'watch1' and 'watch3' both trigger a second time when the value of `$scope.isAuthenticated` changes.

So, this is the general technique to **watch for changes to a *primitive* value that is defined on a service**:

- define an API/method that returns (the value of) the primitive
- $watch that method

To **watch for changes to an *object or array* that is defined on a service**:

- define an API/method that returns (a reference to) the object/array
- In the service, be careful to only modify the object/array, don't reassign it.
    E.g., don't do this: `user = ...;`
  Rather, do this:  `angular.copy(newInfo, user)` or this: `user.email = ...`
- normally you'll assign a local $scope property the result of that method, hence the $scope property will be a reference to the actual object/array
- $watch the scope property

Example:

```
$scope.user = Auth.getUser();
// Because user is a reference to an object, if you change the object
// in the service (i.e., you do not reassign it), $scope.user will
// likewise change.
$scope.$watch('user', function(newValue) { ... }, true);
// Above, the 3rd parameter to $watch is set to 'true' to compare
// equality rather than reference.  If you are using Angular 1.2+
// use $watchCollection() instead:
$scope.$watchCollection('user', function(newValue) { ... });
```

---

Original answer:

To watch the results of a function, you need to pass $watch a function that wraps that function:

```
$scope.$watch( function() { return Auth.isAuthenticated() }, function() { ... });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/wzECr/1/).  In the fiddle, notice how only 'watch3' triggers a second time when the value of `$scope.isAuthenticated` changes.  (They all trigger initially, as part of $watch initialization.)

Comment: Yes that works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation and fiddle too, that makes sense. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Fantastic and straightforward explanation. +1

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your updated solution may be non optimal when you need to watch for changes on large collections. In this case, using your original approach may be preferred.

Comment: Not sure I get this answer.  I get a similar problem and I just have a simple nav bar item:         <p class="navbar-text">User: {{userSession.currentUserEmail}}</p> - it doesn't refresh just like the original poster's situation.  Can I avoid calling a function?  What would I call?

Comment: 1. Using angular.copy() instead of reassignment of array.
2. Setting third parameter of $watch as true.

My problem is solved! Thank you for saving my life, +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

> $scope.$watch(Auth.isAuthenticated(),function () {
>       $scope.user = Auth.getUser()
>   })

to

> $scope.$watch(Auth.isAuthenticated(),function () {
>       $scope.user = Auth.getUser()
>   }, true)

Look at the AungularJs [$watch documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) for a detailed explanation, the default value is false which means that Angular detects changes in the first parameter values by reference, while passing true means the check is done by equality. Being the parameter a function, the check returns always false, since the reference to the function is always the same.

Comment: I don't think this will work: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/wzECr/) -- in both cases, the reference to the function is returned, which doesn't change.  In the fiddle, the watches only trigger once (to initialize themselves).

Answer (score 0):

Using `user` as your variable name is generally not a good idea. I once I changed it ti `currentUser` everything worked for me.