# Getting data from one controller to another with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have got two controllers and want them to send data from the first one to the second one without creating a factory.

```
    module.controller('UpdatesController', function ($scope) {
    var update = {};
    update.items = [{
        title: 'Company goes high',
        date: '24-11-2015',
        excerpt: 'Labore et dolore magna aliqua',
        desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
        picture: 'images/01.jpg',
    }];
    $scope.items = update.items;
    $scope.showUpdate = function (index) {
            var selectedItem = update.items[index];
            update.selectedItem = selectedItem; 
            $scope.navi.pushPage('update.html', {
                title: selectedItem.title,
                date: selectedItem.date,
                excerpt: selectedItem.excerpt,
                desc: selectedItem.desc,
                picture: selectedItem.picture
            });
        };
});

module.controller('UpdateController', function ($scope, items) {
    $scope.item = items;
});
```

But it seems not working. The error is: **Uncaught (in promise) Error: [$injector:unpr]**

Can please anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular sharing data between controllers using service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111536/angular-sharing-data-between-controllers-using-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS, a `controller` can not be injected to other `controller`. If you want the inter-connectivity / sharing in between controllers then you should use factory or service.

In your case, you can do

```
 module.controller('UpdatesController', ['$scope', 'TestFactory', function ($scope, TestFactory) {
var update = {};
update.items = [{
    title: 'Company goes high',
    date: '24-11-2015',
    excerpt: 'Labore et dolore magna aliqua',
    desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
    picture: 'images/01.jpg',
}];
$scope.items = update.items;
TestFactory.setItems($scope.items);
    $scope.showUpdate = function (index) {
            var selectedItem = update.items[index];
            update.selectedItem = selectedItem; 
            $scope.navi.pushPage('update.html', {
                title: selectedItem.title,
                date: selectedItem.date,
                excerpt: selectedItem.excerpt,
                desc: selectedItem.desc,
                picture: selectedItem.picture
            });
        };
}]);

module.controller('UpdateController', ['$scope', 'TestFactory', function ($scope, TestFactory) {
    $scope.item = TestFactory.getItems();
}]);

module.factory('TestFactory', function(){
    return {
      getItems : function(){
        return this.items;
      },
      setItems : function(items){
        return this.items = items;
      }
    }
});
```