# Bidirectional Binding not updating within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble with a bi-directional binding in an ng-repeat.  I would expect for the below $watch to be triggered when you select a color from the list.

```
$scope.$watch('favoriteColors', function (newValue) {
    console.log('example-favoriteColors', newValue);
});
```

I would expect for `Orange` to appear in `$scope.favoriteColors` when checked.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/k5SEQw4XFnxriD2I8ZG7?p=preview

```
directive('checkBox', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        //require: '^ngModel',
        scope: {
            'externalValue': '=ngModel',
            'value': '&'
        },
        template: function (el, attrs) {
            var html =
                '<div class="ngCheckBox">'+
                    '<span ng-class="{checked: isChecked}">' +
                        '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked"/>'+
                    '</span>'+
                '</div>';
            return html;
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
            var initialized = false;
            console.log($scope.value());
            if (angular.isArray($scope.externalValue)) {
                $scope.isChecked = $scope.externalValue.indexOf($scope.value()) > 0;
            } else {
                $scope.isChecked = !!$scope.externalValue;
            }

            $scope.$watch('isChecked', function (newValue) {
                if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
                    //add or remove items if this is an array
                    if (angular.isArray($scope.externalValue)) {
                        var index = $scope.externalValue.indexOf($scope.value());
                        if(index > -1) {
                            $scope.externalValue.splice(index, 1);
                        } else if (initialized) {
                            $scope.externalValue.push($scope.value());
                        }
                    } else {
                        //simple boolean value
                        $scope.externalValue = newValue;
                    }
                    if (initialized)
                        console.log($scope.externalValue);
                }
            });

            $timeout(function () {
                initialized = true;
            });
        }],
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/vQvtz0Afuq7VwBzZoxvT?p=preview

Comment: @Strawberry - The first 2 times I click a checkbox it doesn't trigger the $watch as needed

Comment: I updated it, please take a look now.

Comment: @Strawberry - That's fine for a boolean value, but I'm expecting the console.log() to show: `example-favoriteColors ["Blue", "Orange"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pbHz4ohBPi7iYq6uJI8X?p=preview

There were lots of changes. Some of them are:

- The template needs not be a function, since it is static.
- The `initialized` (and consequently the `$timeout`) is not needed.
- I implemented my own `indexOf` function; there is a chance the objects are not the same in `==` sense, but equals in the `x.name === y.name` sense; (I have some doubts about this though)
- The `add or remove items if this is an array` part was wrong; you need to update the array based on the value of `isChecked`, not based on whether the item already exists in the array (`indexOf`).
- Initialize `favoriteColors` as an array, not as a single object, to be consistent, i.e. `$scope.favoriteColors = [$scope.colors[1]];`
- (minor) Added a little more descriptive log when `favoriteColors` change.
- Use `$watch("favoriteColors", function() {...}, true)` to watch for changes inside the array (not the `true` last argument).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to be referencing a property on an object instead of the flat array. When you pass a primitive data structure like an array, it gets passed by reference and thus the updates aren't passed along properly. ([Post by Mark Rajcok.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391922/1454074))

I went ahead and showed this by hacking your plunkr a little bit. I changed `$scope.favoriteColors = $scope.colors[1];` to `$scope.favoriteColors = {value:$scope.colors[1]};` and changed `<check-box ng-model="favoriteColors" value="color">` to `<check-box ng-model="favoriteColors.value" value="color">`.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oteogGZrkO2IMUKsrRBc?p=preview)

You can see in the plunkr that when you hit the checkboxes the `console.log` statements now go off under the `$watch` function.

Comment: That solution doesn't quite work for what I'm trying to accomplish.  My objective is for each item checked, to make its way into `$scope.favoriteColors`, which is why ngModel references an array instead of a specific value.

Comment: In my example, it is still referencing an array. The array has just been assigned as a property on an object (`$scope.favoriteColors.value = []`).

Comment: Right... there's one small issue where you have to click twice before it registers with the $scope.$watch

Comment: @Webnet, I think if you add a deep watch for the collection it will fire on the first click. http://plnkr.co/edit/o7wxwYtFg0k4kmPT9TKi?p=preview

Comment: @DavinTryon - Your example still doesn't show the right console.log() on the first 2 clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using [angular-form-ui's checkbox directive](http://bkuhl.github.io/angular-form-ui/#!/check-box).

- Use `$watchCollection` ([link to documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection)) instead of `$watch` for watching arrays for changes
- Initialize `$scope.favoriteColors` as an array containing the values that should be checked

I've reverted your changes to `angular-form-ui.js` as those changes broke the directive. They are now exactly as the code appears in the [latest commit on Github (checkbox.js)](https://github.com/bkuhl/angular-form-ui/blob/454c4a1107f42492ce24015bcde6dda438aaacf1/src/directives/checkBox/checkBox.js). Only one thing has changed, the initialization of the `angular-form-ui` module by adding `[]` as the second argument to that first line.

Here is the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mlUt46?p=preview