# AngularJS - return promise success value to the calling function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and AJAX.I am trying to assign the data being returned by the success function to user. grantRole belongs to Auth service. The value of user as I currently have it is a promise. How do I assign the returned data on success to user?

```
$scope.grantRole = function(user) {

  user = Auth.grantRole(user).then(
    function success(data){
        return data;
    },
    function error(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
 );

grantRole: function(user,callback) {
      var cb = callback || angular.noop;
      var data = {id: user._id,controller:'role'};
       return User.update({id: user._id,controller:'role'},data,
          function(user) {
            return cb(user);
          }, function(err) {
            return cb(err);
          }).$promise;
};
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting confused about Promises. Best to find a quick tutorial and learn about the difference in styles between Callbacks and Promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current value of user being a promise is correct. Once the promise gets resolved, it will be assigned to the data returned on success.

But you have to be careful when reassigning objects or arrays. See [Service variable not updating in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380140/service-variable-not-updating-in-controller)

> E.g., don't do this: user = ...;
>
> Rather, do this:  angular.copy(newInfo, user) or this: user.email = ...

```
$scope.grantRole = function(user) {

  Auth.grantRole(user).then(
    function success(data){
        angular.copy(data, user);
    },
    function error(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```